# Highlight next 2 weeks in react datepicker

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I want to highlight the next two weeks from the current date. I am using [react-datepicker](https://reactdatepicker.com/) module. I used the below code:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var numberOfDaysToAdd = 13;
const daysHighlighted = new Array(numberOfDaysToAdd).fill(currentDate);

return (
    <DatePicker
        selected={this.state.startDate}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        highlightDates={[{
            "react-datepicker__day--highlighted": daysHighlighted.map((day, index) => {
                day.setDate(day.getDate() + index)
                return new Date(day)
            })
        }]}
    />
)
```

Which is giving me the unexpected result.

I just want to highlight next two weeks including current Date.

Answer (score 0):

`fill` function fills the Array with same `Date` instance. So whenever you are updating a date with `setDate`, it changes the value of other dates of that array. Because they all point to the same object.

You can try something like this:

```
new Array(numberOfDaysToAdd).fill().map((_, i) => {   // fills the array with `undefined`
  const d = new Date();                               // create a new Date instance
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + i);                         // update only that instance
  return d;                                           // return the updated date
})
```

Now you can use this array as the value of `react-datepicker__day--highlighted` key:

```
<DatePicker
    selected={this.state.startDate}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    highlightDates={[{
        "react-datepicker__day--highlighted": new Array(numberOfDaysToAdd).fill().map((_, i) => {  
          const d = new Date();
          d.setDate(d.getDate() + i);
          return d;
      })
    }]}
/>
```